# Windows task scheduler - CPU temperature trigger

Tags: windows-7, cpu, windows-task-scheduler

Is it possible to run a task using the Windows task scheduler when the CPU reaches a certain temperature?

If it's not possible what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Is possible to trigger an event when the CPU reaches a certain temperature?

[SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) monitors hardware and can read values such as temperatures, fan speeds, voltages, etc. It allows the following to happen when an event (such as the CPU reaching a trigger temperature) happens:

- run a program
- send an email
- display a popup message
- beep

See [SpeedFan's events](http://www.almico.com/sfarticle.php?id=4) for more information.

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.